# How to customize the font of Action Bar tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to set the text font for the ActionBar tabs, is there a way to deal with the textview of each tab?

Comment: Can you please accept my answer?

Comment: its been 3 years, how did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 9):

first you need a `Typeface`

```
Typeface droidSerifMonoTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSerif.ttf");
```

remmber that the font locations is in the assets directory (in this example it's in /assets/fonts/DroidSerif.ttf)

than, for all the tabs, create a textview, assign it the typeface and give it as a custom view to the actionbar's tab:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i) );
            t.setTypeface(droidSansMonoTF);

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setCustomView(t)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }
```