# How (if possible) could I set a custom font in a ActionBar on tab text with a font in my assets folder?

Tags: android-fragments

How (if possible) could I set a custom font in a ActionBar on tab text with a font in my assets folder?
using,  `TypeFace`
please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `view` and add it to the `Tab` as `CustomView`, see my answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/20211563/1726419