# Custom Typeface in ActionBar's Tab Title

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm trying to set a custom Typeface on my `ActionBar` tabs' titles.

I have seen more developers asking for a proper way to do this on SO (e.g. [How to customize the font of Action Bar tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893664/how-to-customize-the-font-of-action-bar-tabs) & [How (if possible) could I set a custom font in a ActionBar on tab text with a font in my assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487834/how-if-possible-could-i-set-a-custom-font-in-a-actionbar-on-tab-text-with-a-fo)) but no answers.

So far, I've followed two approaches:

**1) The first one was *inspired* by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436364/setting-custom-font-for-sherlock-action-bar-tab-android/14681975#14681975) and consists of inflating a custom layout for each tab:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null); // a custom layout for the tab title, basically contains a textview...

TextView titleTV = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.action_custom_title);
        titleTV.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
        titleTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        titleTV.setTypeface(((MyApp) getApplicationContext()).getCustomTypeface());

// ...Here I could also add any other styling I wanted to...

actionBar.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
```

This doesn't look like a very good approach because if the tabs + actions don't fit to the ActionBar in landscape mode, the tab titles are displayed in an overflow list (Spinner/Drop-down) but the selected value shows up as empty. And when you click on this list's item, then all of these views disappear. This is particularly annoying when, for example the user expands a search action view which causes android to show the tab as a Drop-down.

**2) I've tried another approach as presented [here](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/) which involves using a `SpannableString`** but the font doesn't change to my custom one.

```
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "FontName.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(s).setTabListener(this));
```

Class TypefaceSpan can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8).

**So...**

Does anyone know a proper way of styling the `ActionBar` tabs' titles with a Typeface from "/assets/fonts/..."? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

More on the second approach.
The TypefaceSpan class I'm using is actually a fork of [android.text.style.TypefaceSpan](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.java) as presented by user @twaddington here: [How to Set a Custom Font in the ActionBar Title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title/15181195#15181195)

**EDIT 2:**

In the previous link, a comment stated: *"if the textAllCaps attribute is set to true on the underlying TextView (e.g. via a theme), then the custom font won't appear. This was an issue for me when I applied this technique to the action bar tab items"*.

I have changed my style so that textAllCaps was set to false and now the second method seems to work. I'll test it a bit and post the results.

**Conclusion:**

The solution in the previous edit seems to work.

Marking @CommonsWare's answer as correct for its relevancy.

**PS-EDIT for @PeteH:**

I asked this 6 months ago so I don't remember all the details. I believe that for this app I ended up following a different approach for navigation. All I can find now in the app (regarding swiping...) is an `Activity` whose layout contains a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip`, which I styled like this:

```
// Style the Tab Strip:
Typeface tf = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getTabStripTypeface(); // Used this to keep a single instance of the typeface (singleton pattern) and avoid mem. leaks
PagerTabStrip strip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
strip.setTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
strip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
for (int i = 0; i < strip.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = strip.getChildAt(i);
    if (nextChild instanceof TextView) {
        TextView textViewToConvert = (TextView) nextChild;
                    textViewToConvert.setAllCaps(false); 
        textViewToConvert.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

This is not the same as the issue presented in this question, though.

The only related code I can find is this, where I set a `SpannableString`:

```
// For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "FontName.ttf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(s).setTabListener(this));
}
```

...whereas in my styles.xml, I had the style for the Actionbar's Tab Text like this:

```
<!-- action bar tabtext style -->
<style name="ActionBarTabText.MyApplication" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: textAllCaps, nice find and thanks for posting solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypefaceSpan` will only work with the three built-in typefaces.

That being said, [forking `TypefaceSpan`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.java) to use one where the `Typeface` is loaded from a local file path should not be that hard. Rather than treating the `String` in the constructor as being a face family name, you would treat it as an local file path, adjusting `apply()` to load it from there. `Typeface` itself is not `Parcelable`, so you would need to work with the path.

The problem with getting the `Typeface` from assets is that the `TypefaceSpan` would need access to an `AssetManager`, and it would not readily have access to one after being put into and rebuilt from a `Parcel`.

I have not used your first technique, but I am not surprised that you are having problems.

You might also consider dropping action bar tabs entirely and switching to a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, as you may have an easier time styling, say, Jake Wharton's `TabPageIndicator`.

Comment: I'm already using a custom implementation of TypefaceSpan (Question edited) that loads a Typeface from an asset (based on some code by user @twaddington shown here: https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8).

Comment: @user1987392: Personally, I find his implementation a bit disconcerting, as I would expect problems in circumstances where the action bar titles wind up in a `Parcel`. Perhaps that just does not normally happen. Anyway, if you are using his code, remove the `.ttf` from your font name. His implementation appends `.otf` and assumes that your font is in `fonts/` in `assets/`. If you are indeed using a `.ttf` file and/or your fonts are located elsewhere in `assets/`,  you'll need to tweak his code further.

Comment: I've modified his code so that it takes into consideration the extension in the font name provided to the constructor. When debugging, I can see that the Typeface object is created (program would crash otherwise).
I also don't like this approach that much and I'm starting to feel slightly inclined to use the suggested TabPageIndicator or give ActionBarSherlock a try, although I'd much rather prefer sticking to a default approach.

Comment: @CommonsWare the underlying `MetricAffectingSpan` is not a parcelable object. The implementation is incredibly simple. It's just loading a typeface, popping it into an in-memory cache and updating the `TextPaint` used to draw the text. This is all normal framework API code. If you have suggestions on how it can be improved send me an email. We've been using this code in production for almost a year now with no issues whatsoever. The `.ttf` feedback is fair though and I've updated the original answer.

Comment: @user1987392: Would you be so kind as to provide the code for the approach that actually worked for you? I independently attacked this problem in exactly the same order you did but still have been unable to find a working solution.  (I will admit I felt better to see I wasn't the only one coming up short with what seemed like should have been 2 viable approaches.)

Comment: @PeteH see the PS-EDIT. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First look at this example:
[http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/][1]

then create a layout and name it tab_title with the following code:

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/action_custom_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Custom title"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

Then simply in onCreate() method of MainActivity of Androidhive project, just change:

```
 // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
```

To:

```
// Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        TextView customTabView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);
        customTabView.setText(tab_name);
        Typeface typface2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/titr.TTF");
        customTabView.setTypeface(typface2);            
        tab.setTabListener(this);           
        tab.setCustomView(customTabView);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
```

(No need to say that you have to change fonts/titr.TTF to your asset directory and filename)
Joint it!!