# How can I set Typeface in action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, typeface

I have one `Activity` that get `ActionBar` title from `ListView` position in other activity and I want set `Typeface` in `ActionBar`.

```
package com.cambobox.actionbartitle.actionbar;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.TypefaceSpan;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Song extends ActionBarActivity {
Typeface font;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);
   font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/khmerbibleregular.ttf");
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String listview_id = intent.getStringExtra(SongList.NAME);
   ActionBar actionnbar_title = getActionBar();
   actionnbar_title.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
   actionnbar_title.setTitle(font);
   actionnbar_title.setTitle(listview_id);
}
}
```

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077105/custom-typeface-in-actionbars-tab-title may help you

Comment: you have to use custom layout for `ActionBar` .

Comment: check that out http://stackoverflow.com/a/37040611/5319409

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a hack, but it works.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.ITALIC); // add your typeface
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I try it ready it doesn't working. it will better if you can give me the full code.. sorry.

Comment: I edited the answer. This example works for me.

Comment: I have font resource store in Assets/fonts but I get error when I get font from Assets.