# Use custom font on Action bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the font on my action bar tabs but I can't make it work. I already tried a few things and this one looked like the best option. Unfortunately this does nothing and the font remains the same.  I also know that the Typeface is ok because I use it in other parts of my code. This is what I've got:

```
 actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Tab");
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "my_font.ttf");
    s.setSpan(tf, 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    ActionBar.Tab myTab = actionBar.newTab();
    myTab.setText(s);
    myTab.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(myTab);
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can customized the text style of tab by defining the new Tab-Text-Style like that

```
<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

Now set tabTextStyle like that

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You can't do like this because I want to use a custom font.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to use a custom text in actionbar:

```
        ActionBar act = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_custom, null);

        ((MyCustomTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_text)).setText(title);
        act.setCustomView(v);
```

In this case we have a custom `TextView` into a normal layout we inflate to set as a view in the `ActionBar`, the layout will look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ch.nuewsli.widget.TestoTextView 
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@color/WHITE_TEXTCOLOR"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Since it is not possible to change the `ActionBar` font from the xml (but only the font family) you have to extend a `TextView`, force it to use your font and put it into your `ActionBar`, remember to copy your font into the `assets` folder.
The code below is capable to distinguish the style of your `TextView` specified by the `android:textStyle` attribute between `bold` and the others.

**UPDATE**
Just put this code of your `TextView` :

```
   public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    this(context, attrs);
  }

  public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.mContext = context;
    init();
 }

 public void init() {

    Typeface typeface = getTypeface();

    if(typeface != null)
        style = typeface.getStyle();

    if(style != Typeface.BOLD) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "My-Font-Regular.ttf");
    }else {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "My-Font-Bold.ttf");
    }
    this.setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do it programatically? Otherwise you might be able to use a theme for it, i have however noticed that it works differently depending on build targets etc. Here is a sample though:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WorkoutLogActionBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ffffa220</item>
</style>

<style name="WorkoutLogActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/WorkoutLogActionBarTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="WorkoutLogActionBarTitleText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">"sans-serif-light"</item>
</style>
```

This changes font in title on my actionbar, but there seems to be a:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle"></item>
```

Hope this works in your build target version and is of help.

Best regards!

Comment: I think I need because otherwise you can't use custom fonts.

Comment: I see, have you tried using a custom view? As http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893664/how-to-customize-the-font-of-action-bar-tabs

Comment: Yes, I can change the font like that but then I lose all the other customisation that I did