# How to set custom font for TabLayout in Android?

Tags: android

I want use `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in my app, but i want set custom font for `TabLayout` but i can't this!
I use this code :

```
Typeface droidSerifMonoTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSerif.ttf");

for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            t.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i) );
            t.setTypeface(droidSansMonoTF);

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setCustomView(t)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }
```

from this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893664/how-to-customize-the-font-of-action-bar-tabs/20211563) but don't work me!
How can i it?

Comment: any error is coming or font is not applied?

Comment: You use setCustomView() and define the font for the TextView in the layout xml, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout

Comment: @DanielNugent, tnx my dear friend <3

Comment: @Dr.NoBody You can see the solution here in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067265/change-the-font-of-tab-text-in-android-design-support-tablayout

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by extending **TabLayout** class. Override **onLayout** method as bellow:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    final ViewGroup tabStrip = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
    final int tabCount = tabStrip.getChildCount();
    ViewGroup tabView;
    int tabChildCount;
    View tabViewChild;

    for(int i=0; i<tabCount; i++){
        tabView = (ViewGroup)tabStrip.getChildAt(i);
        tabChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
        for(int j=0; j<tabChildCount; j++){
            tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(j);
            if(tabViewChild instanceof AppCompatTextView){
                if(fontFace == null){
                    fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.IranSans));
                }
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Must Overwrite onLayout method, because, when you use **setupWithViewPager** method to bind the TabLayout with the ViewPager, you have to set tabs text either with setText method or in the PagerAdapter after that and when this happened, onLayout method get called on the parent ViewGroup (TabLayout) and that's the place to put setting fontface.(Changing a TextView text cause calling onLayout method of it's parent - A tabView has two children, one is ImageView another is TextView)

**Another Solution:**

First, these lines of code:

```
if(fontFace == null){
    fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.IranSans));
}
```

In above solution, should be written outside of two loops.

But better solution for **API >= 16** is using **android:fontFamily**:

Create a **Android Resource Directory** named font and copy your desired font to the directory.

Then use these styles:

```
<style name="tabLayoutTitles">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/appFirstFontSize</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/vazir_bold</item>
</style>

<style name="defaultTabLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/defaultTabLayoutHeight</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/tabLayoutTitles</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/accomTabIndicatorHeight</item>
    <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/rectangle_white_ripple</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```